# Should I close Streams if I use Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I did small stateless widget that use Streams. I have read that I **always**  should close Streams to prevent memory leak. But Stateless widget do not have `dispose()` method.

So what I should to do? Do not use Streams in Stateless? Or it's ok?

Here is my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Bloc _bloc = Bloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: 
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: _bloc.counter,
          initialData: 0,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> _snapshot)
          {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Pressed: ${_snapshot.data}"),
                RaisedButton(child: Text("inc"), onPressed: () => { _bloc.eventSink.add(IncrementEvent()) },),
                RaisedButton(child: Text("dec"), onPressed: () => { _bloc.eventSink.add(DecrementEvent()) },)
              ],
            );
          }

        )

      ),
    );

  }

}
```

My code base on example from [here](https://pranaybhalerao.wordpress.com/2019/06/11/the-bloc-pattern-from-bad-to-acceptable-flutter-code/).

If memory-leaks please explain how it would be? Every click new object will be created? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

In such a situation, you cannot use a `StatelessWidget`, otherwise you'll have memory leaks and may lose your state.

Convert your widget to a `StatefulWidget` and properly dispose your object.

Comment: Please explain mechanism of memory-leak

Comment: The leak will be the fact that your stream will keep open forever and you will never get that resource back